# Change the name of an item in a custom field using API

Tags: sugarcrm

I am looking for a way to change the names of the items in a custom field I created in studio, without changing their display labels.
I used the field editor (still in studio) to change the associations between names and labels, but despite my modifications, I am still getting the former names (those that were defined before my modifications) when I'm using the API.

How can I make the new names be effective?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

When you change the keys in a dropdown list (you called them 'names'), it will change the language file in SugarCRM, but will not change the existing values in your database.  So a query to existing records that used the old keys will still return those old key values.

You will need to perform UPDATE queries in your database similar to:

```
UPDATE contacts_cstm SET mydropdownvalue_c='NewValue' where mydropdownvalue_c = 'OldValue';
```